# Is google phasing out the Google Docs Viewer?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-apps, google-docs-api

I'm unable to find any reference to the Google Docs Viewer anywhere on the web except on sites from a few years ago. It still works, but I want to be a little more confident before I deploy code that relies on it.

Here's an example of the viewer in an iframe

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf&embedded=true" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hasn't been phased out and in fact there is still small support on Wordpress and Joomla for the same usage.

Your iframe should work fine so long as it is setup correctly.  Here is some short how-to for embedding Google Docs if you run into trouble:

[http://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/google-docs.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230141009/http://wcmshelp.ucsc.edu/advanced/google-docs.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I know it's used on with Gmail and Docs/Drive but the lack of documentation just made me a little wary. My boss and co-workers were pleased with using it as a solution so I guess we'll see how it goes! Thanks again

Comment: is free or comercial Google Docs Viewer?